# Running JHipster microservices with Amazon Cognito

Tags: jhipster, amazon-cognito, jhipster-gateway

I followed the following guide to setup a JHipster generated Gateway with Amazon Cognito: https://blog.ippon.tech/aws-cognito-and-jhipster-for-the-love-of-oauth-2-0/

I got the gateway working great and I'm able to log in into the admin module using Cognito however I am not able to invoke any of the microservices. Any attempt is met with the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null  at
>   com.test.security.oauth2.AudienceValidator.validate(AudienceValidator.java:26)
>     at
>   com.test.security.oauth2.AudienceValidator.validate(AudienceValidator.java:13)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator.validate(DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator.java:67)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.validateJwt(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:165)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.decode(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:126)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(

Debugging show that audience variable is null in the following code:

```
public OAuth2TokenValidatorResult validate(Jwt jwt) {
    List<String> audience = jwt.getAudience();
    if (audience.stream().anyMatch(allowedAudience::contains)) {
        return OAuth2TokenValidatorResult.success();
    } else {
        log.warn("Invalid audience: {}", audience);
        return OAuth2TokenValidatorResult.failure(error);
    }
}
```

I've configured the microservice's application.xml with the following:

```
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          oidc:
            issuer-uri: https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/[secret]
        registration:
          oidc:
            client-id: [secret]
            client-secret: [secret]
```

Has anyone been able to successfully run a jHipster generated microservices platform with Amazon Cognito? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS Cognito doesn't include the audience in the access token so the `validate` methods must be updated.

More details can found here: https://github.com/Falydoor/cognito-jhipster/issues/1#issuecomment-594753033